# Is it a bad practice to use non-latin letters as object property names?

Tags: javascript

I need somehow store Georgian letters and their pronunciation, and later return the pronunciation for a givven letter. The easiest way to do that in my project is to use an object with the letters as property name and pronunciations as corresponding values.

```
const letters = {
    ბ: 'b',
    დ: 'd',
    ს: 's',
    წ: 'ts',
    // and so on
}
```

because later I can get the pronunciation this way:
`return letters[georgianLetter] || ""`

I know any string could be used as a key for an object. But is it a bad practice to use non-latin letters for key names?

I have no idea how else I can implement this and still keep the code simple. I tried to use an array:

```
const letters = [
    ['ბ', 'b'],
    ['დ', 'd'],
    ['ს', 's'],
    ['წ', 'ts'],
    // and so on
]
```

and then get the value like this:

```
return letters.find(item => item[0] === georgianLetter)[1] || ""
```

but it's a bit more complex solution and objects are preferred in this case since they make code shorter and cleaner.

Comment: It is a bad (or least obsolete) practice to use objects for mappings. Use the dedicated `Map` object.

Comment: @gog - Not necessarily, it depends very much on what you're doing with the mapping. For **dynamic** maps, yes, `Map` is the better choice for certain. For static maps as described, not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue to use such character as an object key.

As suggested in a comment, JavaScript has a dedicated tool to handle this use case.

As a better and safer alternative, using the JavaScript `Map` constructor to store your letters would look like this:

```js
const letters = new Map([
  ['ბ', 'b'],
  ['დ', 'd'],
  ['ს', 's'],
  ['წ', 'ts']
]);
    
console.log(letters.get('ბ'));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how is Map structure better and safer in my case?

Comment: It is safer as you are working on characters. Object keys have values that can cause trouble, like using the `"."` character for example. If you are using Typescript or wish to do it one day, you could assign the `Map<string, string>` type to this variable to explicitly say you need a string as an input and get a string as an output. Better because the `Map` usually consumes less memory than an object of the same size, and you could change the dictionary at runtime, let's say if you want to use gregorian to chinese for example.

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann - No, it's not "safer" with the characters the OP said they would be using. And there are **no** characters that are unsafe object properties. There are only characters that you can't use in property name *literals*. `"."` is a perfectly fine property name (assuming you have a good reason for using it). But that's by-the-bye, the characters the OP mentioned are fine for property literals, too. `Map` is a perfectly good alternative, but for a static map like the OP's, it is not objectively "better" or "safer".

Answer (score 4):

> But is it a bad practice to use non-latin letters for key names?

Not at all. JavaScript has defined the valid characters for [identifier names](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#prod-IdentifierName) inclusively almost since inception, using the definition of an "identifier start" and an "identifier part" from the Unicode standard. That means you don't even have to use bracket notation and strings for Georgian letters¹ as you would for some other characters (like `-` or `/`), you can reliably use property literals as you have in your example:

```js
const letters = {
    ბ: "b",
    დ: "d",
    ს: "s",
    წ: "ts",
    // and so on
};

console.log(letters.ბ);
console.log(letters.დ);
console.log(letters.ს);
console.log(letters.წ);
```

You can use an object for what you're doing, or alternatively a `Map`. See MDN's [Maps vs. Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) for several good points on which to choose in any given situation. Since your object is unchanging, it would be fine, but then so would a `Map`.

```js
const letters = new Map([
    ["ბ", "b"],
    ["დ", "d"],
    ["ს", "s"],
    ["წ", "ts"],
    // and so on
]);

console.log(letters.get("ბ"));
console.log(letters.get("დ"));
console.log(letters.get("ს"));
console.log(letters.get("წ"));
```

---

¹ I'll admit I'm assuming here they're all classified as "identifier start." It's easy enough to check in the Unicode Character Properties Utility, for instance [for `ბ`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=10D1).